# Is this user "shadow banned" here (1 rep seems to make no sense, but there's no ban message)?

Tags: discussion, users

[image]

[User link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/210030/user33800?tab=profile) doesn't display any suspension message for me. So how comes his rep is 1 and not 23? (23 is actually correct if you look at his [reputation tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/210030/user33800?tab=reputation).)

Comment: I removed the [meta-tag;bug] because it is not a technical issue of the software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as being shadow banned on the SE network.

The user in question has a question deleted as "spam or offensive," which carries a -100 reputation penalty.

Comment: The user posting an offensive question would not surprise me... He seems to fit the profile of a certain [persistent abuser on another SE site](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/should-we-start-requiring-users-to-register-before-they-can-post-questions). It's weird however that the user rep tabs have such inconsistencies for user penalized for "spam or offensive" posts.

Comment: @Fizz There are a few reputation changes that don't show to everyone. In particular reputation subtracted for downvotes given appears only to the user themselves, since otherwise it would leak private voting information.